# Python Regexp: find all words/phrases within a querystring containing OR and AND

Tags: python, regex

I have a querystring like this:

```
s = 'word1 AND word2 word3 OR "word4 word5" OR word6 AND word7 word8'
```

I need to find all words or phrases within OR and AND, so the results will be a list like this (preferably without the spaces between AND/OR and the word/phrase):

```
l = ['word1', 'word2 word3', '"word4 word5"', 'word6', 'word7 word8']
```

I've tried messing around with regular expressions but could't find a way to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use regexps, re.split should do it:

```
re.split(' OR | AND ', 'word1 AND word2 word3 OR "word4 word5" OR word6 AND word7 word8')
['word1', 'word2 word3', '"word4 word5"', 'word6', 'word7 word8']
```

If you need a bigger hammer, you could check out something like pyparsing:
http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/searchparser.py

Comment: Thanks. That was the answer I was looking for. Did forget about re.split somehow. :)

Comment: +1 for the pyparsing ref. Just splitting on AND and OR discards their separate semantics (AND and OR are not synonymous), and overlooks precedence ("X AND Y OR Z" is different from "X AND (Y OR Z)"). The pyparsing wiki has a couple of examples to start from: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py and http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/searchparser.py.  These examples have also been expanded into their own projects, Booleano and Whoosh.

Comment: For my particular problem it wasn't necessary to know if it is `AND` or `OR`. I just needed the words inside the query, independent from the semantics.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should instead use

```
s.split(' AND ') 
s.split(' OR ')
```

or if the spacing is irregular, use

```
s.split('AND') 
s.split('OR')
```

then loop and `.strip()` each element

Comment: Thx. Though I really would like to find a regex for that. It's not the first time I need sth. like this (this time I just didn't find a work around which satisfies me). There might be even more complex matters with more than just OR and AND as separators.

Comment: fair enough. Though keep in mind the adage "Use the right tool for the right job."  Having a "catch-all" solution is at best overkill, at worst, hard to maintain.  Also, as a general rule of thumb, using regex should always be a last resort solution.  It is a very powerful tool but built-in functions like these are usually always more efficient and more readable.

Comment: Of course. Thanks again for the help. I'll consider you comment for this particular task.